# Find general solution given two particular solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Very simple

We are given the ODE $(t^2-1)\ddot x+4t\dot x + 2x = 6t$

Notice that $t$ and $\frac{t^2+t+1}{t+1}$ are solutions. We are asked to find the general solution.

**What I did:**

Notice that $x_{1} = \frac{t^2+t+1}{t+1} - t = \frac{1}{t+1}$ is a solution to the homogeneous equation, if we had another one, $x_2$, the the general solution would be $c_1x_1 + c_2x_2 + t$.

So really our goal is to find $x_2$.

I tried to do this using the reduction of order method, guessing that $x_2 = vx_1 = \frac{v}{t+1}$ where $v$ is some unknown function of $t$, but that very quickly got out of hand and doesn't seem like the right idea.

I'm open to new directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $v=(t+1)x$ we get $v'=(t+1)x'+x$ and $v''=(t+1)x''+2x'$ and by inserting the original differential equation we get
$$
(t-1)v''=(t^2-1)x''+2(t-1)x'=-2(t+1)x'-2x=-2v'.
$$
Now this can be solved per separation.

Comment: So one can find the homogeneous solution this way; but I don't understand how does having the knowledge of two different particular solutions helps us in this problem? it seems to me that only one particular solution is necessary.

Comment: The difference of two particular solutions is a homogeneous solution. With a homogeneous solution one can apply the (Frobenius?) method of reduction of order. This then hopefully gives the second homogeneous solution $x_2(t)=v(t)/(t+1)$. There is a general formula for the factor $v$, but usually this gives either unsolvable integrals or tracing the steps of its derivation results in earlier simplifications.